# Managing Events -> Log Volunteer hours

Tags: civivolunteer

When logging volunteer hours for events and selecting "no-show" in the status it asks me to put the "Actual Duration". Value '0' or '-' doesnt work.
Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Alek

Comment: What happens if you try to save the record without putting anything in the duration field?

Comment: It says "This Field is Required" for the "Actual Duration" field.

Comment: Hm - I'm able to save it as null - but I can also put the value as 0, I realised (and the same happens on the demo version). Does it accept a positive number when you have 'No Show' selected? What happens if you leave the duration field blank for a scheduled or completed volunteer?

Comment: when Im entering "0", it says "Please enter the actual duration volunteered."
When Im typing in "null" it says it needs a numeric value.
It does accept any value above 0.

Comment: My bad. No-Show does accept values above 0.
I also found out that I can change duration of the volunteering to 0 when I go to the volunteer's profile and I will edit his/her Activity.

Comment: Can I check what version of Civivolunteer you're using? I think this might be related to this issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-34 which was 'fixed' in 1.4.1 but could be causing the problem you're seeing, as the fix involved making the field required. As I'm using 1.4.0 (because I never remember to check for extension updates), the duration field isn't required for no shows. It looks like the demo is also using 1.4.0.

Comment: 4.5-1.4.1 this is what it says

Comment: Let me see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, yes, this is a problem with 1.4.1 - the duration field is required and also seems be set to reject 0 as a value. I'd recommend raising an issue on the CiviCRM issue tracker: https://issues.civicrm.org/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will just keep changing it at the volunteer profile for now. I will also raise the issue.

Comment: No problem :) Add the link to the issue as an answer here when you do.

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-172 here it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the answer, as mentioned by Alek. This is a legitimate bug report and the issue is being tracked here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-172

It is slated to be included in the 2.1 release and a link to the patch will be available on the issue when it is released.